# How shadow a private inner class in Roboelectric?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

How shadow a private inner class in Roboelectric?
My example below:

```
public class A {
           
    private class B {
        read() { }

        public open() {
            read(); 
        }
    }
}
```

How can I shadow read() call inside open() from above example. Thank you.

Comment: shadowing/hiding is term that was coined for static methods (which are not private), when you declare *anything* as private it cannot be "seen" by extending classes, so there's no need to "shadow" or "hide" it!

Comment: Shadowing applies to more than static methods. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1. Likewise hiding applies to more than static methods. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3

Comment: Does Roboelectric have a different syntax than Java? The code example is not valid Java code.